# Please provide me a stub of boost-multi-index - with std::cout

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, logic

I am digging the net & head for multi index, but I didn't find any easy example. Can anybody provide me a small code like multi_index_container with-single_index- find something and cout the value?

Comment: @Nim I got success up to the creation of a multi index container creation,and adding the value. But I dont know the way to find out the particular value and accessing it's corresponding values.

Comment: Post what your container looks like, it may make answers more meaningful. This example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_index/example/complex_structs.cpp, shows how to do searches, i.e. get the index using `get<index tag>(container instance)`, and then uses methods such as those listed here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html#lookup for lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just copy and paste the code from [your other, near-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230845/how-to-get-the-value-out-of-a-multi-index):

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

struct EnumStruct
{
    EnumStruct(int const me, std::string const& mes, int const le, std::string const& les)
      : microsoftEnum(me),
        microsoftEnumString(mes),
        localEnum(le),
        localEnumString(les)
    { }

    int microsoftEnum;
    std::string microsoftEnumString;
    int localEnum;
    std::string localEnumString;
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

struct localEnum_t;

typedef bmi::multi_index_container<
    EnumStruct,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::tag<localEnum_t>,
            bmi::member<EnumStruct, int, &EnumStruct::localEnum>
        >
    >
> boost_Enum_Container;

int main()
{
    boost_Enum_Container enumStructContainer;
    enumStructContainer.insert(EnumStruct(1, "MS_1", 11, "LOC11"));
    enumStructContainer.insert(EnumStruct(2, "MS_2", 22, "LOC22"));
    enumStructContainer.insert(EnumStruct(3, "MS_3", 33, "LOC33"));
    boost_Enum_Container::index_iterator<localEnum_t>::type iter = enumStructContainer.get<localEnum_t>().find(22);
    if (iter != enumStructContainer.get<localEnum_t>().end())
        std::cout << "found, localEnumString == " << iter->localEnumString << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "didn't find anything" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOST_FOREACH(type &i, container.equal_range(key))
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Obviously there is arbitrary number of elements with given key, so this may print any number of lines including zero.

```
std::pair<iterator, iterator> range = container.equal_range(key);
if(range.first == range.second)
    std::cout << "Nothing for " << key << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "First for " << key << " is " << *range.first << std::endl;
```

This is how the equal_range works. It gives you a pair of iterators that mark the range containing values for given key.

Comment: how does this illustrate boost::multi_index?

Comment: To be fair, if you had a `multi_index_container` called `container`, this code is more or less what was requested.  Specifically it does a find operation using the first (0th) index in the container.